# Choice set between a single element and nothing

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to represent a choice set between an element, $a$ and an alternative, nothing, $\emptyset$. Can this set by represented by

S={a,$\emptyset$} or does the empty set have to be a subset of my set S? S={a,{$\emptyset$}}?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually the other way around for your brackets.

$S = \{a\}$, and $\mathcal{P}(S) =\{ \emptyset, \{a\}\}$. You're looking for this powerset.